# Criar objetos dentro de uma lista sem for/foreach C#

Tags: c#, .net, lista

```
private List<Compra> CriarCompras(int numComprasParaGerar)
{
    List<Compra> lstCompras = new List<Compra>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numComprasParaGerar; i++)
       lstCompras.Add(new Compra());

    return lstCompras;
 }
```

Seguindo o exemplo, existe alguma outra forma de criar N objetos dentro de uma lista do mesmo tipo?

#### EDIT

Todas as formas que estão nas repostas funcionam de maneira igual ou similar. Porém, como foi citado pelo @Maniero há um problema enorme de performance em todos eles quando comparados com o `for`.

[Teste realizado pelo @Maniero no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GfDmnz)

Comment: As respostas que usam `Enumerable.Repeat` têm um problema: ele cria uma repetição de **valores**, ou seja, da referência ao objeto passado por parâmetro. De modo que **todos os itens na lista serão o mesmo item**. Ou seja: será criada uma única instância de `Compra` e a referência a esta instância será copiada para cada item na lista - alterando uma das compras, altera-se todas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As respostas que usam `Enumerable.Repeat` têm um potencial problema: ele cria uma repetição de **valores**, ou seja, se o objeto passado por parâmetro é um *reference type* (uma classe, por exemplo), serão feitas cópias da referência ao objeto passado por parâmetro e não cópias do objeto de fato.

De modo que **todos os itens na lista seriam o mesmo item**. Ou seja: se `Compra` é uma classe, será criada uma única instância de `Compra` e a referência a esta instância será copiada para cada item na lista - alterando uma das compras, altera-se todas.

Se isso é um problema para você, apresento abaixo uma alternativa que de fato cria X **diferentes** instâncias.

## Solução que funciona tanto para *reference types* quanto para *value types:*

```
private List<Compra> CriarCompras(int numComprasParaGerar)
{
    return (from i in new int[numComprasParaGerar] select new Compra()).ToList();
}
```

Ou ainda:

```
private List<Compra> CriarCompras(int numComprasParaGerar)
{
    return new int[numComprasParaGerar].Select(i => new Compra()).ToList();
}
```

(eu prefiro a primeira opção, acho mais expressiva).

## Edit:

Concordo em grau e gênero com a edição do @Maniero que diz que o código original do AP é a melhor opção; não por performance mas porque é mais expressivo e tudo nele revela apenas a real intenção sem ter que criar por exemplo um *array* que só serve de artifício para garantir as iterações.

Eu ainda adicionaria o número de compras no construtor da lista e talvez fosse mais além: devolvesse um array em vez de devolver uma lista, retornando no método um `IList<Compra>` ou um `IEnumerable<Compra>` (mas daí tem que ver também o lado do código consumidor - o que é mais cômodo para ele).

**Eu usaria portanto um código mais ou menos assim:**

```
private IList<Compra> CriarCompras(int qtdComprasParaGerar)
{
    IList<Compra> compras = new Compra[qtdComprasParaGerar];

    for (int i = 0; i < qtdComprasParaGerar; i++)
        compras[i] = new Compra();
    return compras;
}
```

Portanto, minha opção usando **LINQ** é apenas para responder diretamente a pergunta (que quer dispensar a declaração do *for*) e para alertar sobre o uso do `Enumerable.Repeat`.

Comment: Muito, muito, muito bem observado.

Comment: Sua resposta salvou vidas agora kkk Eu estava fazendo das outras formas e tentando a edição das compras, não sabia que era criado uma mesma referencia do objeto. Isso realmente gerou problemas. Mesmo tendo várias respostas válidas, a sua resposta foi o que deu origem a edição em todas as outras, então eu escolho a sua. Vlw :D

Answer (score 9):

Você não usou um `foreach`, e nem poderia varrer esta lista. Use o [`Enumerable.Repeat()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.repeat?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Repeat__1___0_System_Int32_) que é um método LINQ.

```
private List<Compra> CriarCompras(int numComprasParaGerar) {
    var lstCompras = new List<Compra>();
    lstCompras.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(new Compra(), numComprasParaGerar));
    return lstCompras;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/s2qeJI). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9xx12U). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/FillList1.cs).

Já que todo mundo arrumou, pra resposta não ficar errada vou escolher a solução que achei mais elegante para resolver a questão.

```
private static List<Compra> CriarCompras(int numComprasParaGerar) => new int[numComprasParaGerar].Select(i => new Compra()).ToList();
```

Veja realmente [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Dg3JtZ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mYUlk2). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/FillList2x.cs).

Veja [como é problemático no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LxGXoy) fazendo de outra forma. E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IaW5IS). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/FillList3.cs).

Já que teve várias respostas e no fundo a pergunta pede algo que não tem tanta necessidade assim, eu um teste rápido de performance. Eu sei que nem sempre deve-se penar na performance, deve-se pensar no que é simples, no que é legível. Mas a performance não pode ser negligenciada em todos os casos.

O que é simples e legível não é unânime. Por exemplo, tem que ache o LINQ como mais simples e legível. Tem quem ache que o código tradicional melhor neste aspecto.

No teste concluí que o código original do AP é o mais rápido com larga margem em relação aos demais.

Por ser a mais rápida e a mais simples na minha opinião, eu ficaria com a solução original do AP. E é o conselho que dou a ele, não mude.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pkjMu2). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GTWGzV). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/FillList4.cs).

Só quero lembrar que o teste em uma máquina pública assim tem pouca confiabilidade. Aconselho rodar em seu computador em condições mais controladas.

Comment: Desculpe o erro na pergunta, editei a mesma.

Comment: Neste caso, dado que sabe o numero de elementos ante mão, não seria benéfico passar o numero de elementos no constructor de forma a evitar uma outra alocação?

Comment: @Omni normalmente sim, neste caso não vai fazer diferença porque está apenas usando um `AddRange` em seguida. Se tivesse usando o `for` como ele estava fazendo, seria altamente interessante usar o construtor que já aloca o espaço necessário para todos elementos e não criar o problema do [Shlemiel the painter](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)

Comment: Eu já havia feito esses testes. Resultado: Mantive a forma original, com for.

Comment: @JonathanBarcela Minha resposta voltou ser a aceita por você então :D Nem estou pedindo pra mudar a aceitação, mas de fato o que você resolveu fazer é o que está na minha resposta. Eu quase coloquei isto logo no início, mesmo sem fazer testes de performance. Optaria por isto só porque é o mais simples.

Comment: @bigown Engraçadinho :D Sua resposta original causou problemas ao AP porque ignorou que `Enumerable.Repeat` só copia valores, lembra?

Comment: @Caffé e daí, a atual foi a que ele escolheu de fato. Se eu tivesse ido no meu instinto a resposta seria justamente, fique com seu código, mas achei que iriam considerar resposta que não responde. Mas pode ficar com aceitação, não estou querendo ela. Pra mim basta que ele fez a escolha certa, mesmo que o verdinho não demonstre isto.

Comment: LoL (realmente rindo aqui hehehe) Por não ter seguido seu infalível instinto ou por qualquer outro motivo, o fato é que você ofereceu uma resposta com erros e aprendeu isso depois que leu a minha resposta. É pra isso que estou aqui: aprender, me divertir e  ajudar. Se pontos fossem do meu interesse eu tava lascado - seria só frustração. Por exemplo, você recebeu 5 votos por uma resposta que não funciona e enquanto ela ainda não funcionava :D (e claro, deve ter recebido muito menos pontos por outras respostas mais relevantes). It's always good to talk to you @bigown (still LoL )

Answer (score 6):

Sim, você pode usar o método [`AddRange()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) e [`Enumerable.Repeat()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348899(v=vs.100).aspx) para isso.

```
private List<Compra> CriarCompras(int numComprasParaGerar)
{
    var lista = new List<Compra>();
    lista.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(new Compra(), numComprasParaGerar);    
    return lista;
}
```

**EDIT**

Como minha internet falhou bem na hora que eu estava postando a resposta e minha resposta ficou praticamente igual a do @Maniero, aqui vai uma alternativa.

```
private List<Compra> CriarCompras(int numComprasParaGerar)
{
    return Enumerable.Repeat(new Compra(), numComprasParaGerar).ToList();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Como foi dito na resposta do @Caffé o `Enumerable.Repeat()` faz com que todos os itens dentro da List sejam o mesmo item. Então, se você precisar que os itens da lista não apontem para o mesmo lugar (o que é **muito** provável), aqui vai uma alternativa.

```
private static List<Compra> CriarCompras(int numComprasParaGerar)
{
    return new List<Compra>(Enumerable.Range(0, numComprasParaGerar).Select(i => new Compra()));
}
```

[Veja funcionando no dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gw2YNQ)

Answer (score 4):

Pode usar [Enumerable.Range()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) para gerar uma sequencia de valores e com um `.Select()` criar as novas instancias e por fim passa-las para o [constructor da lista](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/fkbw11z0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) da seguinte forma:

```
private List<Compra> CriarCompras(int numComprasParaGerar)
{
    return new List<Compra>(Enumerable.Range(0, numComprasParaGerar).Select(i => new Compra()));
}
```

Comment: Ia para editar a resposta, mas invocar o método `.ToList()` (como na resposta do Jeferson), faz o mesmo que a minha resposta (isto e, cria uma nova lista e usa o constructor).

Answer (score 2):

Além das outras respostas, também possível fazer usando a recursão:

```
private List<Compra> CriarLista(int numComprasParaGerar)
{
    var lstCompras = new List<Compra>();
    CriarCompras(lstCompras, numComprasParaGerar);
    return lstCompras;
}

void CriarCompras(List<Compra> lstCompras, int numComprasParaGerar)
{
   lstCompras.Add(new Compra());

   if(lstCompras.Count < numComprasParaGerar)
       CriarCompras(lstCompras, numComprasParaGerar);
}
```