# Como melhorar comparação e concatenação de string C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, concatenação-de-string

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
private static string MontarDescricaoOrgaoUoUe(RequisicaoFisica requisicao)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MontarNomeOrgao(requisicao)) ? MontarNomeOrgao(requisicao)
                    : !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MontarNomeUo(requisicao)) ? MontarNomeUo(requisicao)
                        : !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MontarNomeUe(requisicao)) ? MontarNomeUe(requisicao) : String.Empty;
        }


        private static string MontarNomeOrgao(RequisicaoFisica re)
        {
            var retorno = re.CodOrgaoFpe != null && re.CodUoFpe == null && re.CodUeFpe == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(re.NomeOrgaoFpe)
                ? string.Concat(re.CodOrgaoFpe, " - ", re.NomeOrgaoFpe)
                : string.Empty;

            return retorno;
        }

        private static string MontarNomeUo(RequisicaoFisica re)
        {
            var retorno = re.CodOrgaoFpe != null && re.CodUoFpe != null && re.CodUeFpe == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(re.NomeUoFpe)
                ? string.Concat(re.CodOrgaoFpe, ".", re.CodUoFpe, " - ", re.NomeUoFpe)
                : string.Empty;

            return retorno;
        }

        private static string MontarNomeUe(RequisicaoFisica re)
        {
            var retorno = re.CodOrgaoFpe != null && re.CodUoFpe != null && re.CodUeFpe != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(re.NomeUeFpe)
                ? string.Concat(re.CodOrgaoFpe, ".", re.CodUoFpe, ".", re.CodUeFpe, " - ", re.NomeUeFpe)
                : string.Empty;

            return retorno;
        }
```

Utilizo-o para montar uma "Descrição", utilizando ao todo 6 propriedades do meu objeto. Existe alguma maneira de melhorar este código em performance e legibilidade? Quais?

Comment: Performance, legibilidade ou o que? Pode usar C# 6?

Comment: Tanto performance quanto legibilidade. Acredito que passar o objeto todo não seja a melhor maneira. Meu projeto ainda não está atualizado para o C# 6, se possível utilizar versões anteriores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em performance não consigo ver nada que possa ajudar muito, mas este tipo de coisa só dá para ter certeza fazendo testes em condições reais. A não ser que esteja tendo problemas reais, eu não me preocuparia muito com isto. Eu sempre procuro fazer o mais rápido quando isto é bem óbvio, mas não se ficar ilegível, se o ganho for marginal e desnecessário. Certamente tem algumas coisas aí que poderia dar ganhos marginais mas duvido que algo que compense.

Em legibilidade tem várias coisas que poderiam ser melhoradas, mas nada muito importante. Algumas talvez seja mais gosto.

Eu não uso variável quando ela só vai ser usada uma vez a não ser que isto contribua para a legibilidade, neste caso acho que retornar a expressão direto é melhor.

Por outro lado, no primeiro método tem algumas chamadas de métodos mais de uma vez. Provavelmente - mas não certamente - eu chamaria e guardaria em variável e usaria ela. Isto provavelmente melhoraria a performance, marginalmente.

Este método também está um pouco difícil de ler por ter operadores ternários condicionais aninhados. Dá para entender mas poderia pelo menos organizar melhor. Mesmo não precisando tanto, os demais estão mais organizados e cada operando está mais óbvio.

Algumas pessoas recomendariam você usar `if` no lugar do operador ternário. Ainda mais que você usa variável. Com ela, até faz algum sentido mesmo, por haver efeito colateral. Olhando o código acho uma boa.

No primeiro método talvez usasse `IsEmpty()` já que eu sei que não pode retornar nulo.

Talvez eu repensasse todo este *design*. Mas não sei se dá por não conhecer todos os detalhes do caso, e não é o foco da pergunta.

Acho uma bobagem usar `string.Empty`. Tem quem goste, tem quem ache mais legível, eu não, prefiro `""`. Não tem vantagem alguma usá-lo. Nem desvantagem.

Provavelmente eu usaria o operador `+` para concatenar os textos. O compilador irá transformar eles em `Concat` e eu acho mais legível com os operadores. Tem quem discorde. Eu acho que esta é a parte mais importante da pergunta para o AP. Mas no fundo, não faz diferença.

Se está pensando que precisa usar `StringBuilder`, neste caso não é necessário. Saiba que o `Concat` provavelmente fará uso de um `StringBuilder` se for necessário. O compilador é inteligente para achar a melhor solução neste caso específico. O [assunto já foi tratado em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124/101).

Algumas pessoas vão preferir o uso do [`string.Format()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads). De fato aí é caso para pensar nele. Exemplo:

```
string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}-{3}", re.CodOrgaoFpe, re.CodUoFpe, re.CodUeFpe, re.NomeUeFpe)
```

Ou em C# 6:

```
$"{re.CodOrgaoFpe}.{re.CodUoFpe}.{re.CodUeFpe}-{re.NomeUeFpe}"
```

Outra coisa que eu provavelmente pensaria em fazer é encapsular estas condições complexas em métodos específicos que retornem um `bool`. Assim dá nome para esta condição, não fica parecendo uma coisa mágica, e dica mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), mais canônico, facilitando a manutenção. Em que classe colocar esses métodos é uma arte :)

Tem outras melhorias possíveis se puder usar C# 6. A verificação de `null` pode ser dispensada. Pelo menos tem sintaxe melhor.

Um exemplo do que provavelmente eu faria:

```
private static string MontarDescricaoOrgaoUoUe(RequisicaoFisica requisicao) {
    var texto = "";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MontarNomeOrgao(requisicao)) texto = MontarNomeOrgao(requisicao);
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MontarNomeUo(requisicao)) texto = MontarNomeUo(requisicao);
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MontarNomeUe(requisicao)) texto = MontarNomeUe(requisicao);
    return texto;
}

private static string MontarNomeOrgao(RequisicaoFisica re) => re.CodOrgaoFpe != null && re.CodUoFpe == null && re.CodUeFpe == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(re.NomeOrgaoFpe) ?
        re.CodOrgaoFpe + " - " + re.NomeOrgaoFpe :
        "";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/CompareAndConcat.cs).

Pela sua [pergunta anterior sobre laços](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89611/101) me parece que você gosta de fazer tudo no menor número de linhas possível. Não tente fazer isto. Pode piorar a legibilidade, o entendimento de todos os envolvidos e até piorar a performance.

Comment: Não é que eu goste de "fazer tudo no menor número de linhas possível", eu apenas gosto de ver como os outros fariam o que eu fiz. Ter N maneiras diferentes pra fazer a mesma coisa. Obrigado pelo resposta, irei melhorar algumas coisas para melhorar a legibilidade. Uma ultima coisa, o meu objeto usado tem cerca de 30 propriedades. É correto passar ele ao invés de só passar as props que vou usar?

Comment: Bom, isso já é outra pergunta, mas o mais comum é usar o objeto todo. Isto dá mair acoplamento mas em geral facilita muito e não costuma causar problemas, porque você já tem que contar com este acoplamento. Tem uma regrinhas conceitais para decidir quando passar o objeto e quando passar propriedades individuais, mas na pra´tica a que conta mais é a quantidade que tem que passar. Muitos parâmetros se torna inviável. As regras valem mais quando vai acessar apenas uma propriedade do objeto. Não é certo que deva passar a propriedade. Olha só, ficou maior que muita resposta :)

Comment: Melhorei a resposta, consegui visualizar melhor. Eu adicionei informações lá na outra pergunta e te aconselhei ficar com seu código :)

Comment: Uma dúvida: No C#6, `$""` não é um açúcar sintático para `string.Format`?

Comment: @renan Não. De fato eu comi bola ali em usar o `string.Format()`, ele é desnecessário, mas não é *sugar*. É um substituto, sem dúvida, mas com características e semântica diferente. Você pode entender melhor as diferenças em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101